# Opening ssh connection using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess

I'm opening an ssh session using `subprocess.Popen` with the `shell=True` flag set. The script is run by systemd as root. I took an strace from the ssh client and found:

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0xbe87d254)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl64(0, F_GETFL)                     = 0x20800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl64(0, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, 0xbe87d254)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl64(1, F_GETFL)                     = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl64(1, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)             = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0xbe87d254)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fcntl64(2, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1583787257, tv_usec=193031}, NULL) = 0
shutdown(3, SHUT_RDWR)                  = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It looks like the standard streams are not set correctly. I am using the `-T` flag to disable psuedo-tty allocations. I thought that `shell=True` would set these.

When the same script is run from the command line, the connection stays open (Probably because the STDIN and STDOUT are set). I'm not checking the output or supplying input to process, its solely for port forwarding. What should I set `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to in my `Popen` call to prevent this? I've tried `subprocess.PIPE` and piping within the shell command to no avail.

I am also running this from a thread shortly before it exits. Could that have something to do with it? I thought `Popen` was supposed to launch a new process (not a child) if pipes were not specified.

Edit: Here's the Popen call:

```
command = shlex.split("ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no " +\
                        "-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "+\
                        "-i identityFile "+\
                        "-p 64046 user@"+ssh_target+" "\
                        "-R 64045:127.0.0.1:22 -g " \
                        "-b " + bind_address)

sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the full `subprocess` call? Preferably a full script we can experiment with.

Comment: @tdelaney, updated the post. Sorry I can't include the full script because of NDAs. If I can't get an answer I'll rewrite something similar that reproduces the issue.

Comment: That's enough.... Assuming you wait on the Popen object before exit

Comment: I am not calling wait because I need it to be non-blocking... is there any way to "fire-and-forget" the process? I don't expect the ssh process to close quickly, and the parent is waiting for the thread to exit before other important tasks.